# Angular Set value to MatInput type time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a matInput field of type time which I want to set the HH:mm of a new Date () variable, when I use [value] I can do it, but I would like to know how to do it using formControlName.

component.html

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pl-sm-8 no-errors-spacer" fxFlex="50">
                <mat-label>Time:</mat-label>
                <input matInput
                       type="time"
                       formControlName="Time_start" 
                required>
            </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
      createComposeForm(): FormGroup
      {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
          Time_start : [''],
        });
      }

      ngOnInit(): void
      {
        this.form = this.createComposeForm();
        let fechaInicioValue = new Date(this.VarWhitTheDate);
        this.form.get('Time_start').setValue(= new Date(fechaInicioValue ););
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is OK. And make sure your `form-field` is nested under `form`.

And you have to convert your date to time string to work.

So, setting the value will look like:

```
this.form.get("Time_start").setValue(this.getTimeAsString(fechaInicioValue));
```

The conversion function:

```
getTimeAsString(date: Date) {
    return `${date.getHours()}:${(date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "") +
      date.getMinutes()}`;
  }
```

Working solution at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-uwx7he?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you must add same workaround to hours
(HH:mm) -> 03:04

```
getTimeAsString(date?: Date) {
        return `${(date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getHours()}:${(date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getMinutes()}`;
    }
```